# preg_replace on string that contains recurring signs

Tags: php, regex

I have to filter strings like these:

```
[{'Mo-Do':['09:00-20:30']},{'Fr':'09:00-21:00']},{'Sa':['09:00-20:30']}]
```

I wanted to do this with a preg_replace, so that the string looks after this like:

```
Mo-Do: 09:00-20:30, Fr: 09:00-21:00, Sa: 09:00-20:30
```

Unfortunately, I am relatively inexperienced in dealing with regular expressions.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is the `[` in `Fr` ?

Comment: That's almost JSON if it wasn't missing `[` and had double-quotes.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/b1UiP

Comment: Thanks thats also really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $re = '/[\[{\]}\']*/m';
    $str = '[{\'Mo-Do\':[\'09:00-20:30\']},{\'Fr\':\'09:00-21:00\']},{\'Sa\':[\'09:00-20:30\']}]';
    $subst = '';

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

    echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;

    ## Output:  Mo-Do:09:00-20:30,Fr:09:00-21:00,Sa:09:00-20:30
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H7FSKi/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats really nice!